# Contact listener error

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

When I use this code, I'm getting error.and the error line is which one is with "if". why?

```
     private ContactListener contactListener()
    {
        ContactListener contactListener = new ContactListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void beginContact(Contact contact)
            {
                final Fixture x1 = contact.getFixtureA();
                final Fixture x2 = contact.getFixtureB();
                if(x1.getBody().getUserData().equals("player"))
                {

                }
           }

            @Override
            public void endContact(Contact contact)
            {
            }   
         };
         return contactListener;
    }
```

**Error**

[image]

Comment: What error you occurred ?

Comment: http://s24.postimg.org/tdl4kqgp1/Capture.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
if (x1.getBody().getUserData()!=null && x1.getBody().getUserData().equals("player") ||
        x2.getBody().getUserData()!=null && x2.getBody().getUserData().equals("player"))
```